# How to send json type array $.post to phalcon

Tags: jquery, post, phalcon

I'm trying to send a form with data type array[] 
And I'm having trouble processing them on the phalcon controller

```
  <form id="form_access" name="form_access" >
  <table class="table table-hover">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name="codigo[]" id="codigo[]" value="100" />                      
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="access[]" id="access[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="insert[]" id="insert[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="edit[]" id="edit[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="delete[]" id="delete[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name="codigo[]" id="codigo[]" value="101" />                      
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="access[]" id="access[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="insert[]" id="insert[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="edit[]" id="edit[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="delete[]" id="delete[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name="codigo[]" id="codigo[]" value="102" />                      
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="access[]" id="access[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="insert[]" id="insert[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="edit[]" id="edit[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="delete[]" id="delete[]"  value="1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

 </table>
 </form>
```

It´s my jquery

```
    str = $("#form_access").serialize();

    $.post("access/save",str, function(data){  
        console.log(data);
    },'json');
```

And it´s my controller

```
 public function saveAction()
{

    $this->view->disable();

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {


        $codigo = $this->request->getPost("codigo");
        $access = $this->request->getPost("access");
        $insert = $this->request->getPost("insert");
        $edit = $this->request->getPost("edit");
        $delete = $this->request->getPost("delete");

        $data = array();

        foreach ($codigo as $key => $value)
        {
            $data[] = ($value." - ".$access[$key]." - ".$insert[$key]." - ".$edit[$key]." - ".$delete[$key]);
        }

        $this->response->setJsonContent(array('res' => $data));
        $this->response->setStatusCode(200, "OK");
        $this->response->send();
    }

    $this->response->setStatusCode(400, "NOT FOUND");
    $this->response->send();

}
```

But in my console I get this

```
{"res":["100 -  -  -  - ","101 -  -  -  - ","102 -  -  -  - "]}
```

Apparently I'm just getting the data from the first foreach I make.

Something I'm doing wrong, help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "access/save",
  data: str,
  success: success,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

More info in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Probe with that too and I'm still giving it back {"res":["100 -  -  -  - ","101 -  -  -  - ","102 -  -  -  - "]}

Comment: Well, them maybe you want to rephrase your question, there's nothing wrong with the js, problem must be in the back-end..

Answer (score 0):

**Action **

```
   $request = new \Phalcon\Http\Request();
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        $this->view->disable();
        if ($request->isAjax()) {

            $codigo = $this->request->getPost("codigo");
            $access = $this->request->getPost("access");
            $insert = $this->request->getPost("insert");
            $edit = $this->request->getPost("edit");
            $delete = $this->request->getPost("delete");
            $data = array();
            foreach ($codigo as $key => $value) {
                $data[] = ($value . " - " . $access[$key] . " - " . $insert[$key] . " - " . $edit[$key] . " - " . $delete[$key]);
            }

            $this->response->setJsonContent(array('res' => $data));
            $this->response->setStatusCode(200, "OK");
            $this->response->send();
        }

    }else{
        $this->response->setStatusCode(400, "NOT FOUND");
        $this->response->send();
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // process the form
    str = $("#form_access").serialize();
       $.post("/access/save", str, function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       }, 'json');

});
```

**Result**

```
Object
res:Array[3]
0:"100 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1"
1:"101 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1"
2:"102 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1"
length:3
```